# Битрикс установка заголовка ответа страницы

Tags: http, битрикс, cors

На основе Битрикса делаю API для приложения.
Есть ли возможность в обращаемом файле устанавливать заголовки ответа от сервера?
В документации битрикса нашел только:

```
use Bitrix\Main\Web\HttpClient;

$httpClient = new HttpClient();
$httpClient->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', true);
```

Но это для запросов с сервера. Есть ли какой-то метод установки заголовков ответа на конкретной странице или все придется настраивать у сервера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например в template.php компонента можно вызвать:

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
if($arResult["STATUS"] != "error")
{
    $json = array(
        "total" => $arResult["TOTAL"],
    );
    foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem)
    {
        $arJson = array(
            "ID" => $arItem["ID"],
            ...
        );
        $json["records"][] = $arJson;
    }
}
else
{
    $json = array(
        "status" => "error",
        "message" => $arResult["MESSAGE"],
    );
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: header() - точно,спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант:

```
<?
//$app = Application::getInstance();
$app = Bitrix\Main\Application::getInstance();
$responseHeadersHandler = $app->getContext()->getResponse()->getHeaders();
$responseHeadersHandler->set('header_name', 'header_value');
```